# Encoding Time Values

Tags: python, neural-network, scikit-learn, data-cleaning

I am using Python/Scikit to do data encoding before I go ahead and train my Neural Network. I have a few columns that look like this

```
07:05:00
08:41:00
17:25:00
12:58:00
08:56:00
11:59:00
17:25:00
15:24:00
```

Any suggestions on how to encode this? Or is leaving it like this fine?

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/2370/23305

Comment: i recommend using datetime in python to extract features from the timestamp: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to convert the strings into seconds. Since these are all Time of Day values, I will convert them to contiguous seconds.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663720/converting-a-time-string-to-seconds-in-python

Comment: in your training (and test) data did you then replaced the Date_time column with a 'contiguous_secs' (int) column?

Answer (score 2):

A common step in "feature engineering" is parsing these out into multiple values that might give you additional information during ML. For example:

- Hour of the day
- Minute of the hour
- Hours after sunrise
- Hours before sunset

If you also had day, that would open a lot more to detect seasonality like:

- Month of the year
- Month of the quarter
- Day of the week
- Holiday Y/N