# Converting dates to appropriate form to train machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning-model, data-science-model

I am trying apply linear regression on a dataset where the independent variable is a date formatted like '2-jan-08'. How should I convert the date so it can be used for model fitting?

Comment: Current question is too broad to be answered correctly. Post a part of your data or dummy data having a similar structure, to let others help you better.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether the date is the single source of features data **X** or if the date is a feature of **X**, along with other features.

If the date is the only independent variable you have [time-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series) models, such as the autoregressive (AR), integrated (I) or moving average (MA) models. Their combination results in the ARMA or in the [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) models. Check this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/arima-for-time-series-forecasting-with-python/) on using ARIMA with Python

If the date is a feature among others, you can convert the original date into multiple date features. Check this [thread](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/2368/machine-learning-features-engineering-from-date-time-data) for feature engineering with time data.